# Getting event admins

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-apps

Is there any way to get admins of an event. Or we can filter from Attending users that whoever is admin or not.

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to retrieve the admins of an event, apart from the creator. I don't believe it's possible.